# Can't pass nil to UIAlertView init method

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm trying to create a UIAlertView that has no message. According to the documentation, the declaration for that init method is:

```
init(title title: String?,
          message message: String?,
         delegate delegate: AnyObject?,
cancelButtonTitle cancelButtonTitle: String?)
```

however when I call that method like so:

```
UIAlertView(
    title: "Undo",
    message: nil, 
    delegate: self, 
    cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", 
    otherButtonTitles: "OK")
```

I get an error "Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'".

The **message** parameter is an optional String, so why can't I pass nil to it?

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling

```
init(title: String?, message: String?, delegate: AnyObject?, cancelButtonTitle: String?)
```

You're calling

```
convenience init(title: String, message: String, delegate: UIAlertViewDelegate?, cancelButtonTitle: String?, otherButtonTitles firstButtonTitle: String, _ moreButtonTitles: String...)
```

because of your `otherButtonTitles` parameter, which has the `message` field declared as `String`, and therefore not optional.